# Aligning a group of radio button vertically and divide it if necessarely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radiobuttonlist

I have been looking for a solution for this problem but I couldn't find any in particular satisfying my request so it would be really cool if any of you can help!

The problem is that I have for example 7 radio buttons aligned vertically inside a DIV tag but I want to find a way (a JavaScript function for example) to divide them in two groups dynamically for example 4 buttons on the left side and the 3 left on the right.

For now, I just hard coded it by adding two other div child-tag inside the parent one and putted them beside each others, but this won't solve my problem!

For example, I have this code right now:

```css
.radioButtonList{ 
 width: 300px;
    margin-left: 1px;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.radioButtonListDevidedFirst{ 
 width: 100px;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
}

.radioButtonListDevidedSecond{ 
 width: 200px;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radioButtonList"> 
  <div class="radioButtonListDevidedFirst">
   <div class="radioItem">
  <dspel:input type="radio" id="X" bean="Y" value="blue" checked="${CONDITION}"/>
  <label for="value"><fmt:message key="keyExample" bundle="${myBundle}"/></label>
   </div>
   <div class="radioItem">
  <dspel:input type="radio" id="X" bean="Y" value="blue" checked="${CONDITION}"/>
  <label for="value"><fmt:message key="keyExample" bundle="${myBundle}"/></label>
   </div>
   <div class="radioItem">
  <dspel:input type="radio" id="X" bean="Y" value="blue" checked="${CONDITION}"/>
  <label for="value"><fmt:message key="keyExample" bundle="${myBundle}"/></label>
   </div>
   <div class="radioItem">
  <dspel:input type="radio" id="X" bean="Y" value="blue" checked="${CONDITION}"/>
  <label for="value"><fmt:message key="keyExample" bundle="${myBundle}"/></label>
   </div>
  </div>
     
  <div class="radioButtonListDevidedSecond">
   <div class="radioItem">
    <dspel:input type="radio" id="X" bean="Y" value="blue" checked="${CONDITION}"/>
    <label for="value"><fmt:message key="keyExample" bundle="${myBundle}"/></label>
   </div>
   <div class="radioItem">
    <dspel:input type="radio" id="X" bean="Y" value="blue" checked="${CONDITION}"/>
    <label for="value"><fmt:message key="keyExample" bundle="${myBundle}"/></label>
   </div>
   <div class="radioItem">
    <dspel:input type="radio" id="X" bean="Y" value="blue" checked="${CONDITION}"/>
    <label for="value"><fmt:message key="keyExample" bundle="${myBundle}"/></label>
   </div>
  </div>
     
</div>
```

Comment: please share some relevant code so that we can help you better. Share your html and script code

Comment: I wasn't looking for an already developed code, I just asked if someone had an idea or a trick that could help me. Thanks anyway for your concern but I already had an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try CSS3 [column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)

```css
div {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 1
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 2
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 3
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 4
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 5
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 6
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 7
  <br>
  <div>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer pal, that was what I was looking for! I didn't know these attributes existed. You made my day ;)