# Make a list arrange in columns

Tags: html, css

I have a list as such:

[image]

It's a simple list, which I am trying to edit in css.

How can I make the list arrange in perfect columns, e.g. make a pre-defined space between each element so that it will self-arrange?

I've tried messing with padding and margin but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: did you try taking fixed width for all `li` elements

Comment: Can you at least show your code, so we can see what's happening? I think it just need `display:inline-block;`.

Comment: I would suggest you to use table if you have a tabular data to be arranged as shown. 
If in case you do not want to opt out for tables, then you could take a clue from grid layout using floats. [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/)

Comment: you can use table or use div for each columns.

Comment: CSS Columns woudl be optimal here

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594052/aligning-a-group-of-radio-button-vertically-and-divide-it-if-necessarely/36594399#36594399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try CSS3 **[column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)**

```css
div {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 1
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 2
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 3
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 4
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 5
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 6
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 7
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 8
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 9
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 10
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="group">Option 11
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `<li>`s to `display: inline-block;` and give them a `width: 33.33%;`, so they'll be arranged in three columns.

I wouldn't spend much effort on the horizontal distance between the columns unless the text labels may become two wide and have to break into multiple lines. If you need to allow for that, you could set `display: table-cell` instead and add a `padding-right:` of the desired vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `div` to enclose the lists with a `float` property ,and then set the `margin` value to control the space,see my following demo .

```css
.list {
   float:left;
   
}
.list1 {
 margin-right: 20px; 
 
} 
.list2 {
 margin-right: 20px; 
 
}
```

```html
<div  class = 'list list1'>
  <ul>
    <li><input type = 'checkbox'><span>AAAAAAAA</span></li>
    <li><input type = 'checkbox'><span>AAAA</span></li>
    <li><input type = 'checkbox'><span>AA</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div  class = 'list list2'>
  <ul>
    <li><input type = 'checkbox'><span>BBBBB</span></li>
    <li><input type = 'checkbox'><span>BBBBBBB</span></li>
    <li><input type = 'checkbox'><span>AA</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div  class = 'list list3'>
  <ul>
    <li><input type = 'checkbox'><span>CCC</span></li>
    <li><input type = 'checkbox'><span>CCCCCCCC</span></li>
    <li><input type = 'checkbox'><span>CCCC</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ups can use `inline-block or float` for that with width in percentage %

```css
.test{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 50px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
 }
.test li{
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing:0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
.test2{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
.test2 li{
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  }
```

```html
    <ul class="test">
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="test2">
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
              <li> <input type="checkbox"/>  content</li>
    </ul>
```